# How to authenticate and create a Push notification Subscription to get Outlook email @mentions?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to authenticate in order to use Outlook REST API to subscription to Outlook emails via Push Subscription. I am using this documentation for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations

I created an app in portal.azure.com and provided Required permission on "Read user mail" under "Office 365 Exchange Online" api.

[Grant Required permission of Read user mail Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okzds.png)

I am using the following code to get a Bearer token using "Microsoft.Identity.Client" nuget package. But I am still not able to subscribe to the Outlook Push Notification REST API and I am getting 401 Unauthorized error.

```
  static async Task<AuthenticationResult> AuthorizeAsync(string clientId)
    {
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com";
        var app = new PublicClientApplication(clientId, authority);
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "Mail.Read" };
        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        if (accounts.Any())
        {
            authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var username = $"{Environment.UserName}@microsoft.com";
                authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuthAsync(scopes, username);
            }
```

Has anyone worked on a similar issue to authenticate and create a Push notification Subscription to get Outlook emails and can please help?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the Outlook Rest API rather than the Microsoft Graph? Plenty more samples there https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample and a hands on lab too https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-webhooks-customdata-insights/blob/master/Lab.md#2-microsoft-graph-webhooks

Comment: Hi Jeremy, currently I am using the Microsoft Graph after your reply. t.But I am still not able to subscribe to the Microsoft Graph Push Notification REST API and I am getting 400 Bad Request error. Can you please help. I have posted link to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661716/400-bad-request-error-on-using-microsoft-graph-api-to-subscribe-to-outlook-push

Comment: Hi JeremyThakeMSFT, I was able to successfully create a subscription using ngrok for notification url. But this subscription is for notifying all the emails and not just @mentions. Is there a way to to filter only mentions in the email? Thank you

Comment: unfortunately not. The subscription allows you to subscribe to all activity in the users inbox. From there you can inspect each message to see whether there are mentions in it. This is actually a neat request, if you could request it on UserVoice i'll talk to the PMs about this becoming a feature https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: This would be very helpful.  Also, it looks like there already is a uservoice request for $filter support with webhook subscriptions here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33570451-add-filter-support-for-webhook-subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for voting it up!